# console.log error / value below was evaluated just now

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, speech-recognition, console.log

I'm making a voice recognition program and when I press the microphone button, an error occurs and I can't record. Is there any way to fix it?

It is written 'react' and this foundation 'react-c l i'

there has problem to Speech Recognition Error"Value below was evaluated just now.". I used chrome.

I think it maybe console.log() has the problem

how to solve this problem? Please help
if you need more problem information please leave your comment

```
state = {
show: false,
listening: false,
text: "Sorry, can't hear",
};
component Did Mount() {
const Recognition =
window.Speech Recognition || window.web kit Speech Recognition;
if (!Recognition) {
alert(
'Speech Recognition API is not supported in this browser, try chrome'
);
return;
}
this.recognition = new Recognition();
this.recognition.lang =  'k o-KR';
this.recognition.continuous = false;
this.recognition.interim Results = false;
this.recognition.max Alternatives = 1;
this.recognition.on result = event => {
  const text = event.results[0][0].transcript;
  console.log('transcript', text);
  this.set State({ text });
};
this.recognition.on speech end = () => {
console.log('stopped');
this.set State({ show: true });
};
this.recognition.on no match = () => {
console.log('no match');
this.set State({ text: "Sorry, can't hear" });
};
this.recognition.on start = () => {
  this.set State({listening: true});
};
this.recognition.on end = () => {
  console.log('end');
  this.set State({listening: false});
  this.end();
};
this.recognition.on error = event => {
console.log('error', event);
this.set State({
show: true,
text: event.error
});
};
```

"error 
SpeechRecognitionError {isTrusted: true, error: "not-allowed", message: "", type: "error", target: SpeechRecognition, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: SpeechRecognition
continuous: false
grammars: SpeechGrammarList {length: 0}
interimResults: false
lang: "ko-KR"
maxAlternatives: 1
onaudioend: null
onaudiostart: null
onend: ƒ ()
onerror: ƒ (t)
onnomatch: ƒ ()
onresult: ƒ (t)
onsoundend: null
onsoundstart: null
onspeechend: ƒ ()
onspeechstart: null
onstart: ƒ ()
**proto**: SpeechRecognition
defaultPrevented: false
error: "not-allowed"
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
message: ""
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: SpeechRecognition {grammars: SpeechGrammarList, lang: "ko-KR", continuous: false, interimResults: false, maxAlternatives: 1, …}
target: SpeechRecognition {grammars: SpeechGrammarList, lang: "ko-KR", continuous: false, interimResults: false, maxAlternatives: 1, …}
timeStamp: 14645.344999998997
type: "error"
**proto**: SpeechRecognitionError"

Comment: I see that the error says not-allowed. Are you sure you gave access to the microphone in your browser?

Comment: I realized that http doesn't allow microphone authority. how do I solve this problem?

Comment: You can host it through localhost and Chrome will let you use the microphone without any problem. Or if you have the project uploaded on your server you can grab a free SSL certificate through Let's Encrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/)